# Join of normal subgroups of a group is normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Prove that the join of any nonempty collection of normal subgroups of a group is an normal subgroup.

Attempt:

Let $\left\langle\bigcup H\right\rangle$ be the join of $H$, where $H$ is the join of any nonempty collection of normal subgroups of $G$.

Let $g\in G$. Then $g\left\langle\bigcup H\right\rangle g^{-1} = g\left\langle \bigcup H_i\right\rangle g^{-1} = \left\langle g\bigcup H_ig^{-1}\right \rangle= \left\langle\bigcup gH_ig^{-1}\right\rangle = \left \langle \bigcup H_i\right\rangle = \left \langle \bigcup H\right\rangle $ So $\left\langle \bigcup H\right\rangle $  is normal.

I don't know if this is a good way to approach this. Can someone please help? Maybe there is a better  approach.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\{H_a\mid a\in A\}$ be a family of normal subgroups of $G$, we must prove $L=\left\langle\bigcup\limits_{a\in A}H_a\right \rangle \lhd G$. So take an element in $L$. It is of the form $h_1 h_2\dots h_n$ with $h_i\in H_a$ for some $a\in A$ for every $1\leq i\leq n$.

We must prove $g(h_1 h_2\dots h_n)g^{-1}\in L$

Now notice $g(h_1 h_2\dots h_n)g^{-1}=(gh_1g^{-1})(gh_2g^{-1})\dots (gh_ng^{-1})$. And because each $H_a$ is normal we notice if $h_i\in H_a$ then $gh_ig^{-1}\in H_a$. Therefore $g(h_1 h_2\dots h_n)g^{-1}\in L$ as desired.

Comment: Thank you , your proof is much simpler!

Comment: How come an element in $L$ is of the form $h_1 h_2\dots h_n$ with $h_i\in H_a$ for some $a\in A$ for every $1\leq i\leq n$?

Comment: It's not ? ${}{}$

Comment: Might have made a mistake, haven't done this in a while but if iirc the join is characterized like that.

Comment: I don't know. That's why I'm asking. (Please don't forget to tag me in all replies, like this: @Yorch.) I'm refreshing my knowledge . . .

Comment: @Shaun, the finite expressions of that form form a subgroup as they are closed under inverses and products, and contain e. Moreover any finite group containing the union must have all of those expressions, so the join is characterized in that way

Comment: Thank you, @Yorch :)

Comment: My pleasure @Shaun

Comment: I wrote "finite group" instead of "subgroup" :/